# Issue trying to parallelise code with OpenMP - deadlock on 2 threads

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I am writing code to update a 2D array until the maximum difference is below a certain threshold. I wrote the serial code and it works fine. I am now having issues parallelizing the code using OpenMP. Below is the section where it seems to hang if I set the number of threads to be 2. (Note: I am still learning OpenMP).

```c
    float max_diff = 1.0;
    while (max_diff >= 1e-4)
    {
        max_diff = 0.0; // reset max_diff on each iteration
#pragma omp parallel private(i, j) shared(n, w, w_new)
        {
#pragma omp for reduction(max : max_diff)
            for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) // loops from 1 till n - 1 to ensure no out of bounds in the max_diff update
            {
                for (j = 1; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    w_new[i][j] = (w[i + 1][j] + w[i - 1][j] + w[i][j + 1] + w[i][j - 1]) / 4.0;
                    max_diff = fmax(max_diff, fabs(w_new[i][j] - w[i][j])); // returns either max_diff or the difference between w_new and original w array.
                }
            }
       }
        float **temp = w;
        w = w_new;
        w_new = temp;
    }
```

I tried different approaches but it still seems to deadlock here for 2 threads. It runs when setting the threads to be 4 but it is slower than the serial execution or execution with 1 thread. I can provide the full script if requested. I have spent days at this and I can't find a way to parallelize it properly. Please help!

EDIT 1: I have updated the code slightly. I added a print statement to print the values of `max_diff` along with the thread number to check for synchronisation. I also added `#pragma omp single` at the end so no race conditions occur when copying the array.

EDIT 2: Further fixed code to my most updated version. Moved the `reduction` clause to the loop region and removed `omp single` clause and put pointer swapping outside of the parallel region. Still running slow with 2 threads+.

EDIT 3: Including full source code below. Compiled with `gcc -o steadyState steady_state.c -fopenmp -lm`. Running on a VM with dual core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90 GHz. `gcc` version 4.8.5 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44). 4 GB of RAM also.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("Running...\n");
    FILE *outFile;
    outFile = fopen("2darray.txt", "w");
    float **w;
    int n = 100;
    int nthreads;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments!\n");
        printf("Correct usage: %s nthreads\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    nthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
    printf("Number of threads used: %d\n", nthreads);

    // initialise 2D array 100 x 100
    w = (float **)malloc(n * sizeof(float *));

    int i, j;
    // allocate memory for each row
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        w[i] = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    }

    /* initialise array with given values
    first row: 0.0
    last row: 100.
    first column: 100.
    last column: 100
    all other elements: 75.
    */
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(n, w)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < n - 1) // first row
            {
                w[i][j] = 0.0;
            }
            else if (i == n - 1) // last row
            {
                w[i][j] = 100.0;
            }
            else if (j == 0) // first column
            {
                w[i][j] = 100.0;
            }
            else if (j == n - 1) // last column
            {
                w[i][j] = 100.0;
            }
            else // all other elements
            {
                w[i][j] = 75.0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Initial array set!\n");

    /* update interior values */
    float **w_new; // make new array from copy of original
    w_new = (float **)malloc(n * sizeof(float *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        w_new[i] = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            w_new[i][j] = w[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("New array copied! Updating new array...\n");

    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    float max_diff = 1.0;
    int iterations = 0;
    while (max_diff >= 1e-4)
    {
        max_diff = 0.0; // reset max_diff on each iteration
#pragma omp parallel private(i, j) shared(n, w, w_new)
        {
#pragma omp for reduction(max : max_diff)
            for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) // loops from 1 till n - 1 to ensure no out of bounds in the max_diff update
            {
                for (j = 1; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    w_new[i][j] = (w[i + 1][j] + w[i - 1][j] + w[i][j + 1] + w[i][j - 1]) / 4.0;
                    max_diff = fmax(max_diff, fabs(w_new[i][j] - w[i][j])); // returns either max_diff or the difference between w_new and original w array.
                }
            }
            //printf("max_diff: %.3f\thread: %d", max_diff, omp_get_thread_num()); //optional print statement for debugging

        }
        // swap pointers
        float **temp = w;
        w = w_new;
        w_new = temp;

        iterations++;
    }
    printf("Maximum difference now less than 1e-4! Stopping.\n");
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    double time = end - start;
    printf("Time taken to reach tolerance: %.12f s\n", time);

    // print array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            fprintf(outFile, "%.1f  ", w[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(outFile, "\n");
    }
    fclose(outFile);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free(w[i]);
        free(w_new[i]);
    }
    free(w);
    free(w_new);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `local_max_diff` should not be shared. Please use a [`reduction` clause](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html) instead of rolling your own using a critical section.

Comment: Copying `w_new` to `w` is quite expensive. Try swapping pointers instead.

Comment: @paleonix I have introduced a `reduction(max : max_diff, local_max_diff)` clause and removed the critical section as well. I am still getting the same issue. I have also introduced pointer swapping instead of the copying section. I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly you should not need `local_max_diff` anymore. `reduction(max : max_diff)` gives you a private/"local" variable that will be reduced to a shared variable automatically. Please edit the updated code into your question.

Comment: @paleonix I have updated the code. `max_diff` seems to be reducing per thread but it is different per thread. For example, the `max_diff` on thread 0 is 0.056 while it is 0.026 on thread 1 (when running at 2 threads). I tried putting in an `ordered` clause for `max_diff` in the loop but no changes.

Comment: How is the w_new and w declated?

Comment: You have to put the `reduction` clause on the `#pragma omp for`, so the reduction happens at the end of the loop instead of the end of the parallel region.

Comment: I think the pointer swap should not be inside a `single` region. With the parallel region being inside the `while` loop here, I would just put the swap outside the parallel region.

Comment: Assuming `n` is much bigger than the number of cores on your computer, you don't need to `collapse` the loops. Some OpenMP implementations implement the `collapse` in a less than ideal way.

Comment: I put the `reduction` in the right place, removed the `collapse` declaration as well moving the `single` section out of the parallel region. I am now getting a somewhat desirable printout. Here's a snippet:
`
max_diff: 0.03455       thread 1
max_diff: 0.03447       thread 1
max_diff: 0.03447       thread 0
max_diff: 0.03440       thread 0
max_diff: 0.03440       thread 1
max_diff: 0.03432       thread 1
`
The `max_diff` variable seems to be passed successfully between threads. It is just really slow (factor of 100) compared to serial execution. Thank you for your replies @paleonix

Comment: What are you timing? If it's just this section  of the code, and this is the first OpenMP parallel region, you are also measuring thread creation time...

Comment: I hope you are measuring time without the print statements in there.

Comment: @JimCownie yes just this section of code. When running with 1 thread, the execution time is ~1.2 s. With two threads it is ~48 s without any print statements. I expect there is additional overhead with more threads but I wouldn't expect it to be this much slower.

Comment: @paleonix Yes, I don't have any print statements when timing.

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Use optimized builds (`-O2` or `-O3`) for benchmarking, results from unoptimized/debug builds are not useful. How big is `n`?

Comment: For stencil codes in particular it might actually make sense to use `collapse` in combination with tiling (introducing additional loops over tiles in both dimensions) to minimize the surface to volume ratio of the memory regions read by different threads and therefore minimizing false sharing of the halos. But if `n` is big enough I wouldn't expect false sharing to be a big problem either way.

Comment: @paleonix `n=100`. When I build with `-O2` it takes 0.30s for 1 thread and 48s for 2 threads. Since my n is quite small I (100x100 array) I don't see the need for a `collapse` region.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bad performance when trying to write code around yours. Please include a minimal, reproducible example as well as information on the hardware that you are running on, and the complete compiler command and version. How many iterations does the code run with your initialization?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem even with ancient gcc 4.8.5. I always get almost double performance with two threads compared to one. My guess would be that it is an issue with your VM and its resources.

Comment: @paleonix I just got the same results as you when running on my computer. Thank you very much for going through the problem with me. Seems like a big waste of time now but at least I learnt something!